# Cucumber feature file when converted in java Datatable is not giving null value in string

Tags: java, cucumber

Considering I have following datatable in feature file when converted to POJO say ABC with fields a, b, c... with a integer, b and c as string I want blank spaces represented in datatable to be converted to null values and not empty string. How can I do so, any input? Currently its converting to empty spaces.

| A | B | C |
| 1 |   | c |
| 2 | b |   |

More info if required:
cuke version: 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this done directly, as Cucumber has no "special encoding" for null in a DataTable, and therefore parses empty cells into empty Strings. What you can do, is deal with this in your POJO that reflects this row, *assuming* these cells should always be null whenever they get empty strings, something like:

```
public class ABC {
     int a;
     String b;
     String c;

     public int getA() {
        return a;
     }

     String getB() {
          return b.isEmpty() ? null : b;
     }

     String getC() {
          return c.isEmpty() ? null : c;
     }
}
```

Then use these getters (and not the members directly) when you use this data in your Step code.

Comment: ok, basically there is no way to differentiate between null and empty. gotcha. thanks